# Is there any way to get vs code to stop prompting to delete a file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way to get vs code to stop prompting to delete a file?

Right now I get "Are you sure you want to delete?" "You can restore from trash."

Yes every application ever made… I'm sure. Stop asking.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to File -> Preferences -> Settings and then search for `confirm delete`. This should then display the "Explorer: Confirm Delete" option:

[image: Explorer: Confirm Delete]

Comment: This appears to be broken now (2022-08-24). I've added this setting for user, workspace, and remote. I've reloaded vscode, and double checked the setting in settings.json, and am still prompted for deletion (on mac over ssh session to a linux box).

Comment: @EricFitting same issue here

Answer (score 4):

This is not currently possible, no.

However, you can upvote [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/19545) and hope it gets fixed. Or you can try to create a pull request help yourself and others :-)